# Roulette probabilities when betting on 2 rows/columns

Tags: probability

I was recently reading about parrondo's paradox and just as an exercise I was looking at the game of roulette. What I came up with doesn't really seem to relate to parrondo's paradox but it does seem off knowing how casino's like to maintain an edge. I may have missed something painfully simple and would like some input

In an American roulette wheel there are 36 numbers and 2 zeros(zero and double zero). A row/column contains 12 numbers and there are 3x rows and 3x columns. The probability of any one spin containing a number in a row/column should be $\frac{12}{38}=\sim31.57\%$ and any two rows $\frac{24}{38}= \sim63.15\%$. If the payout for a row/column is $2:1$ then the expected value for one row/column is $(0.3157*2)-(0.6843*1)=-0.0529$ or $-5.29\%$. Two rows/columns would have an expected value of $(0.6315*2)-(0.3685*2)=0.526$ or $26.3\%$. Am I missing something simple where the expected value for playing 2x rows/columns would be negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in the \$2 you assign to winning when betting on two rows: you would only win \$1, since you have bet on a losing row as well. Therefore, your expected earnings are:

$$\frac{24}{38} \cdot 1 - \frac{14}{38} \cdot 2 \approx -0.1053$$

Betting on two rows thus results in an expected los of approximately \$0.11.

Comment: Thanks! I knew it had to be something simple I was missing.